# Where are updated files with version number in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I updated my wordpress a couple of days ago and now a plugin is using the following file:

```
http://tuhrig.de/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105
```

I want do edit this file, but I can't find it. I know where the original file is (in *wp-includes/js/thickbox* of course...), but however, when I change it, it doesn't affect the file with the new version number. So, where is that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your own version of `thickbox.js`. I mean put it in some place into your plugin dir and include it:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my_thickbox', PLUGIN_URL . '/js/thickbox.js');
```